# UE4 Gear VR won't "lock to HMD"

Tags: unreal-4, virtual-reality

**the problem:**

"Is Head Mounted Display Enabled" seems to always return false on samsung Gear VR.
so the camera is not locked to the HMD and it will use the default camera's not the ones for hmd. 
the checkboxes under the camera settings are checked.

---

**how to reproduce:**
 (osig and nvpack is already
    installed)

1. create a clean Top Down blueprint
   template "Mobile/Tablet", "Scalable
   3D or 2D", "No Starter Content"
2. enable the plugins "Gear VR" and the
   "Oculus Library" and disable all
   other in the VR section.
3. in the project settings configure
   for andriod, set the minimum and
   target SDK version to 19, turn on
   "configure the android minifest.xml
   for deployment for gear vr".
4. package the project for "Android
   ETC2".

---

**hardware:**

Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge (SM-G935F)

Gear VR (SM-R322)

**software:**

Android 6.0.1

UnrealEngine 4.12